# Reading the request body with nickel.rs

Tags: stream, rust

I would like to send a request to my API and put some binary data in the body of the request, but nickel.rs doesn't seem to have a way to handle streams.

I can get the POST parameters and parse them into JSON, but how can I read the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nickel is built on top of [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper), and the [Nickel `Request`](http://docs.nickel.rs/nickel/struct.Request.html)  exposes the original hyper request:

```
pub struct Request<'a, 'b, 'k> {
    pub origin: HyperRequest<'a, 'k>,
    pub route_result: Option<RouteResult<'b>>,
    // some fields omitted
}
```

That, in turn, implements the `Read` trait:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate nickel;

use nickel::Nickel;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    server.utilize(router! {
        post "**" => |req, _res| {
            let mut body = vec![];
            req.origin.read_to_end(&mut body).unwrap();
            format!("You posted {} bytes", body.len())
        }
    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this as soon as I can.

Comment: What I want, to be exact, is write body's data as soo nas they come in a file. I don't want to download all the body and then write, I want to write it byte per byte, as soon as they come.

Comment: @Jhun that's fine. `req.origin` implements `Read` which will let you stream things. I honestly don't know exactly when the handler is called, like if Nickel waits for the whole thing to be buffered or not.

Comment: `curl --request PUT -d "test" http://127.0.0.1:6767/test` returns me `You posted 4 bytes.` ... So it works ! Now I need to know if nickels waits about all the data, or if I can put some code between the moment when nickels reads the first byte, and the last.